# Prove that in a 5-regular and 4-edge connected graph, every edge is in a perfect matching

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a 5-regular graph and 4-edge connected graph, I want to prove that every edge is in some perfect matching.

I can prove that for any edge $xy$, the graph $G-\{ xy\}$(delete the edge $xy$ from $G$) has a perfect matching by using Tutte's Theorem, however, I cannot derive the conclusion from what I have proved. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Does $G-\{xy\}$ mean that you are deleting the edge $xy$, or the vertices $x$ and $y$?  If the latter, then you're done.  Add $xy$ to the perfect matching.

Comment: @saulspatz It means delete the edge $xy$

Comment: Are you thinking about this with the nowhere zero 3-flow conjecture in mind, by any chance?